# Tabs прыгает при нажатии

Tags: html, javascript, css

Друзья, при клике в табах по ссылке прокручивается страница к верху!
Как пофиксить это?

Код:

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#" title="tab1">111</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="tab2">222</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="tab3">333</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="tab4">444</a></li> 
<li><a href="#" title="tab5">555</a></li>    
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
<div id="tab1">
    1
 </div>
<div id="tab2">
    2
 </div>
<div id="tab3">
    3
     </div>
<div id="tab4">
    4
     </div>
<div id="tab5">
    5
 </div>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#content div").hide();  
            $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current");  
            $("#content div:first").fadeIn();

            $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();        
                $("#content div").hide();  
                $("#tabs li").attr("id","");  
                $(this).parent().attr("id","current");  
                $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); 
            });

        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: в представленном примере ничего не прыгает: http://jsfiddle.net/z9oLz7cd/

Comment: В примере не прыгает, потому что он итак наверху страницы, и выше прыгать уже некуда

Answer (score 3):

`href="#"` убрать с `a`. Он из-за решетки прыгает, как бы якорь на эту же страницу.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); исключает прыжки по якорям

Comment: e.preventDefault();  да исключает - но не работает =(((

Comment: так а решение с href не помогло?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" title="tab1">111</a></li>
```

ставим в код HTML действие по клику и скачки к якорям прекратятся